# How can I install Bugzilla on OS X without duplicating TeXlive?

Tags: macos, macports, tex, bugzilla

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/255617) convincingly argues that there is no way to determine the storage needed to install a MacPorts package.

Also, as is clear from this [Q](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50470/9549) & [A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50502/9549) it's a bad idea to install TeXlive using MacPorts since it becomes difficult to maintain it. It's much better to install an external TeXlive.

MacPorts has a recipe for installing Bugzilla, but during a dryrun (`-y`) I see `texlive-bin` in the list of packages Bugzilla depends on, which means that it will be duplicated.

Is there a way to install Bugzilla on a Mac (with or without MacPorts) without duplicating TeXlive?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  `port rdeps --no-build bugzilla`[1] shows no texlive-bin or any other tex-related ports that I'm aware of.  I don't know that much about bugzilla but I can't imagine why it needs tex.

However, we have no maintainer for the bugzilla port.  MacPorts is at version 4.4.5 whereas the current release is 5.0.3.  It is also using MySQL version 5.1 which is getting pretty old.  I wouldn't mind helping but it will be at least a few days before I could take a look at this.  You might file a ticket with MacPorts requesting the update.

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Tickets

There is already a ticket regarding the database issue:

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/43431